# how to look through divs in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I was able to loop through the DB and get results that i wanted. However, the way the result is displayed is what i trying to achieve. Here is the code displaying my result from the DB in wordpress
[result of the page when i implemented the code below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fg70.png)
[This what i really want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wmw0.png)

```
<?php $loop = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'education_detail', 'orderby' => 'post_id', 'order' => 'ASC'));?>

                <?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();?>


                  <div class="resume">
                    <ul class="timeline">
                        <li class="timeline timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="posted-date">
                                <span class="month"><?php the_field('resume_year')?></span>
                            </div><!-- /posted-date -->
                            <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInUp">
                                <div class="timeline-content">
                                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                                        <h3><?php the_field('school_name')?></h3>
                                        <span><?php the_field('course_study')?></span>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-heading -->

                                    <div class="timeline-body">
                                        <p><?php the_field('course_description')?></p>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-body -->
                                </div> <!-- /timeline-content -->
                            </div><!-- /timeline-panel -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


                <?php endwhile;?>
```

Nevertheles, here is the code for the html version of the same website

```
 <ul class="timeline">
                        <li>
                            <div class="posted-date">
                                <span class="month">2007-2011</span>
                            </div><!-- /posted-date -->

                            <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInUp">
                                <div class="timeline-content">
                                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                                        <h3>Bachelor degree certificate</h3>
                                        <span>BA(Hons) in UI Engineering, Arts University, Pabna, USA</span>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-heading -->

                                    <div class="timeline-body">
                                        <p>I have completed UI Engineering degree from ABC University, Boston, USA at feel the charm of existence in this spot, which was creat.</p>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-body -->
                                </div> <!-- /timeline-content -->
                            </div><!-- /timeline-panel -->
                        </li>

                        <li class="timeline-inverted">
                            <div class="posted-date">
                                <span class="month">2004-2006</span>
                            </div><!-- /posted-date -->

                            <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInUp">
                                <div class="timeline-content">
                                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                                        <h3>Higher Secondary certificate</h3>
                                        <span>Typography Arts, FA College, New York, USA</span>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-heading -->

                                    <div class="timeline-body">
                                        <p>From this college of existence in this spot, which was created for the bliss of souls like mine. I am so happy, my dear friend.</p>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-body -->
                                </div> <!-- /timeline-content -->
                            </div> <!-- /timeline-panel -->
                        </li>
```

My question is how can i achieve the second class in my WordPress version so that i can have the same interface as my HTML

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a counter to check if your post is odd or even.
When you have your counter you do a little if to check if the post is even or odd when its odd you add a class.

```
<?php while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();?>
                  <div class="resume">
                    <ul class="timeline">
                        <?php 
                         $postcount++; 
                         if(($postcount % 2) == 0 ){
                          echo '<li class="timeline">';
                         }else{
                          echo '<li class="timeline-inverted">';
                         }
                        ?>
                            <div class="posted-date">
                                <span class="month"><?php the_field('resume_year')?></span>
                            </div><!-- /posted-date -->
                            <div class="timeline-panel wow fadeInUp">
                                <div class="timeline-content">
                                    <div class="timeline-heading">
                                        <h3><?php the_field('school_name')?></h3>
                                        <span><?php the_field('course_study')?></span>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-heading -->

                                    <div class="timeline-body">
                                        <p><?php the_field('course_description')?></p>
                                    </div><!-- /timeline-body -->
                                </div> <!-- /timeline-content -->
                            </div><!-- /timeline-panel -->
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

Something like this maybe.